# Risk that apps with access to your saved files and camera roll get a hold of all your saved files and photos

Tags: privacy, android, mobile

Since I made pictures of some documents that should never be released to the public I was wondering how high the risks actually are, that the pictures I made have been "saved" by some of my apps, or are just floating through the web at the moment.

For context, I gave some apps (especially apps I just downloaded sometimes for fun and then forgot, like "MakeApp") the permission to access my files and my camera roll, since this is needed for photo editing apps and the like.

However, I never opened any of said pictures with an app like this, and had them just sitting on my phone for a while. Thus my main concern comes back to the possibility, that some apps just save all of the files on default.

Comment: I think that this question cannot be properly answered. In general the risk is low that some arbitrary app downloaded from Google  play store shows such a malicious behavior. But, the risk is not zero - i.e. any app which you've allowed to get such access might in theory copy these data to some server in the internet without you noticing. And how much  the risk is with your specific (and mostly unknown to us) apps can not be estimated. If you have valuables at home you don't invite strangers and let them freely move around - and that's what you should not do with your phone either.

Comment: Once an application is granted permissions to access your photos/files, it might exfiltrate data in the background at will. I wrote an application for testing purposes some time ago to find out. The app sent all pictures to my server once it had the permissions to do so.